# Insert records for each calendar date across multiple time series data in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, date, android-sqlite, sql-insert, date-arithmetic

I have an API which pulls time series data for different categories. For some categories it only pulls weekday data.

I would like to fill in the Saturday/Sunday data with the preceding Friday. I also need to backfill for public holidays too i.e. a Monday bank holiday which is not in the original time series will also be filled with the preceding Friday. See table below for illustration. I have assumed 8/8/2022 is bank holiday for illustrative purposes.

I have used the answer from [Insert records for each calendar date in SQLite table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70787467/15597975) to perform this on a single time series set. I would like to know how I can apply this backfill logic for each respective categories time series. i.e. category 1 uses category 1 friday data, category 2 uses category 2 friday data etc.

I am using sqlite version 3.18.

### Before (current data)

[image]

### After (desired result)

weekends added in green, bank holidays added in grey

[image]

### Code that works on Single Category

From [Insert records for each calendar date in SQLite table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70787467/15597975). Can the code be adjusted to work on multiple categories to achieve *desired result* above?

```
CREATE TABLE BALANCES (Category varchar(25), BalanceDate DATE, Amount INT)

INSERT INTO BALANCES VALUES
('cat 1',date('2022-07-25'),101),
('cat 1',date('2022-07-26'),102),
('cat 1',date('2022-07-27'),103),
('cat 1',date('2022-07-28'),104),
('cat 1',date('2022-07-29'),105),
('cat 1',date('2022-08-01'),106),
('cat 1',date('2022-08-02'),107),
('cat 1',date('2022-08-03'),108),
('cat 1',date('2022-08-04'),109),
('cat 1',date('2022-08-05'),110)

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT b1.Category, date(b1.BalanceDate, '+1 day') BalanceDate, b1.Amount FROM BALANCES b1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BALANCES b2 WHERE b2.BalanceDate = date(b1.BalanceDate, '+1 day')) AND date(b1.BalanceDate, '+1 day') <= DATE('now')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Category, date(c.BalanceDate, '+1 day'), c.Amount FROM cte c
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BALANCES b WHERE b.BalanceDate = date(c.BalanceDate, '+1 day')) AND date(c.BalanceDate, '+1 day') <= DATE('now')
)
INSERT INTO BALANCES(Category,BalanceDate, Amount)
SELECT Category, BalanceDate, Amount FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the condition for `Category` in the `WHERE` clauses:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT b1.Category, date(b1.BalanceDate, '+1 day') BalanceDate, b1.Amount FROM BALANCES b1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BALANCES b2 WHERE b2.Category = b1.Category AND b2.BalanceDate = date(b1.BalanceDate, '+1 day')) 
    AND date(b1.BalanceDate, '+1 day') <= DATE('now')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Category, date(c.BalanceDate, '+1 day'), c.Amount FROM cte c
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BALANCES b WHERE b.Category = c.Category AND b.BalanceDate = date(c.BalanceDate, '+1 day')) 
    AND date(c.BalanceDate, '+1 day') <= DATE('now')
)
INSERT INTO BALANCES(Category,BalanceDate, Amount)
SELECT Category, BalanceDate, Amount FROM cte;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7397da92bae36663c0fa21465c796b66).